# Hibernate: InstantiationException en consulta

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

estoy iniciandome en Hibernate y no logro entender porque me falla justo la línea en la que recojo el resultado de la query y lo guardo en una lista: List listaUsuarios = consulta.list();

La consulta en cuestión:

```
public List<Usuario> listarTodo(){

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Query consulta = session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuario u");
    List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = consulta.list();
    
    return listaUsuarios;
}
```

Comment: Probaste a incluir la ruta de la clase en la query? En vez de `Usuario`, `com.tusPaquetes.Usuario`

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el stacktrace completo de la excepción? Puede haber más informacion en las excepciones anidadas.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo una consulta de hibernate mia. Creo saber tu posible error.

```
public static List CiudadesDeUnPais(Country pais) {
        String nombreCiudad;
        List<String> nCiudades = new ArrayList();
        Session sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = sesion.beginTransaction();
        Query consulta;
        consulta = sesion.createNativeQuery("SELECT city FROM City where country_id =:pais").setParameter("pais", pais);
        nCiudades = consulta.getResultList();
        tr.commit();
        sesion.close();
        return nCiudades;
    }
```

creo que seria consulta.getResultList();